# How many times render will actually run in a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component, react-lifecycle-hooks

I was going through React LifeCycle methods when I got stumbled on this:

[image]

I got confused as I am seeing render() function to run 2 times. All I know is that any function in *React Life-Cycle* runs only once. So, why am I seening 2 render functions here (or running 2 times). Won't it affect the memory and overuse for running 2nd time.

Also, How we know where render function would run (or at what stage) as it can run at 2 places in *React Cycle*. Kinldy, help clarify.

**Reference:**

https://gist.github.com/bvaughn/923dffb2cd9504ee440791fade8db5f9

Comment: Where do you see it running 2 times ? It runs once when mounting and once when updating. Those are 2 different things

Comment: The first one is the initial render call during Mounting, the 2nd one is every subsequent render.

Comment: "All I know is that any function in React Life-Cycle runs only once" - that's not true at all. Some of them only run once during a component's lifecycle, such as `componentDidMount` or `componentWillUnmount`, but some of can run a limitless number of times, such as `render` or `componentWillUpdate`. As for your question, `render` runs when the component mounts, *and* every time the state or props change, UNLESS you implement a custom `shouldComponentUpdate` function, which you can use to look at the current and previous props/state and manually control if it should re-render

Comment: Render can also re-run if the parent re-renders, though there are ways to avoid this (which is a good idea, since you may not always want to re-render a component just because its parent re-renders). There are posts/articles about ways to do that

Comment: OP, you don't think render runs twice only, based on this list, do you? The entire *Updating* part will run multiple times, over and over, while the component is mounted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a component, the `render()` function obviously can run more than once for the same mount. You may refer to [this](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) table from the React docs.

From the table, it's clearly that if a component is mounted, only `constructor` and `componentDidMount` will run once (excluding `componentWillUnmount` which also run once when the component is unmounted), while the other lifecycle methods can run unlimited times, depends on the number of updates of that component.

Answer (score 3):

> Mounting

At first, Reactjs will render method only once and the lifecycle would be:

```
constructor();
static getDerivedStateFromProps()
render();
componentDidMount();
```

> Updating

But as you update `component state or on receiving new props` will trigger
the following lifecycle:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps()
shouldComponentUpdate();
render();
getSnapshotBeforeUpdate();
componentDidUpdate();
```

note that, returning false from `shouldComponentUpdate()` will not trigger render

All methods except `render()` are optional

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is that whenever a value of state or prop will change,your render method will run until and unless you are force stopping by returning false from of the life cycle method as @Navin Gelot mentioned,then it will not run render method otherwise yes.